# Find the axis of symmetry in a point cloud

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, computational-geometry, data-analysis

I have some dataset which describes a spherical cloud of points in 4D space. Actually, the coordinates of the points are the coefficients of unit quaternions, so you get the idea on what the data is like.

I have to write a program that verifies the **assumption** that the cloud has one axis of symmetry, which goes through 2 opposite locations on the sphere, let's say its "north" and "south" poles, with the points supposedly arranged symmetrically around the axis in "rings" of 2-4 points. (existance of any of these is not known, this is the very assumption I want to check)

However, it is not known, where exactly are the poles on this sphere and what is the orientation of this axis.

The question is - how do I find the four-dimensional line which is the axis of the symmetry? If the assumption is wrong and the symmetry does not exist in this point cloud, then this also could serve as an answer.

I would really appreciate some help on this since I'm struggling with this for some quite time already.

In my attempts I tried to approach the problem by first proving the existance of the point rings around the hypothetical axis. If these rings to be found, they'd give a good hint about the axis. I was doing this by finding points with equal distances between them, but it gives too much noise and is very time consuming. I am currenlty attempting to advance on this approach, but I thought what if there's some easier way? Or probably, an already known easier algorithm to acheive that?

**UPDATE:**

To clarify on the question in the comment by Adam: probably yes, the "axis of symmetry" most likely is not the correct term (I am sorry, just no idea, how to describe it). Yes, probably I went too far in attempt to describe it with 3D analogy..

So that's how I was thinking: if this was a 3D case, then the points would be settled on rings like the black dotted rings on this picture (I apologize for it being not a mathematical picture, but that's really the best example I could find): [image: 3D example]

So if on each ring there sat, say 3 dots separated by equal distances, then, if you project them on a plane that is orthogonal to the red line, and connect the projections of all the points of a certain ring, you would get a picture of concentric equilateral triangles. If the triangles are aligned with each other, we could even project this to 1D and still see an order.

But if we'd look at the set of these 3D points without the projection and even without the sphere, then, from an arbitrary angle, we would probably never guess that there is an order. They'd seem totaly random.

Similar to this there should be a way to to project this 4D sphere into a 3D sphere, which later we can project on a 2D plane and see a similar pattern. This is exactly what I am after.

It is interesting to note that during my research I project the datasets onto the 6 planes: xy, xz, xw, yz, yw and zw, and I had a couple of "lucky" datasets of this kind, which were making this kind of regular patterns on some of the planes. It could not be a blind chance since the patterns were very regular. I am trying to prove that all datasets can give such a projection if the projection planes are chosen correctly, or if there is the hypothetical "axis" which can be "rotated" to rotate the sphere and cause the abovementioned projections reveal the regular shapes.

So ultimately I am looking for a way to rotate the sphere to get the projection of the regular shapes, and I thought that finding the handle for the rotation - the "axis" - would be a start.

I really wish I could explain this better.. sadly I lack the necessary vocabulary, so I have to explain by example and analogy.

Comment: What do you mean by 'axis of symmetry'? If this were in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I would understand it to mean 'axis of a non-trivial rotation preserving your point cloud', but rotations in $\mathbb{R}^4$ don't have 'axes' per se (they preserve planes rather than lines).

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher Thank you for this meaningful inquiry. Please look I have updated the question.

Comment: I got rid of the general topology tag, since it is not appropriate.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Okay, sure! I thought that topology might relate in the way that I am looking for a pattern in the topology of the cloud, but if it's incorrect to say it this way, then I guess you know it better than me :)

Comment: I would try computing the quadrupole moment tensor Q and then diagonalizing it. Any basis in which Q is diagonal is likely to coincide with the symmetry axes of the cloud.

Comment: @BenCrowell seems a direction to go! I have found some papers by google search on "quadrupole moment tensor", found http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0902/0902.4073.pdf , http://www.pa.msu.edu/people/stump/EM/chap3/3ex3.pdf and some other papers.. currently studying them. It will take some time for me to parse them, however from the brief skimming of the papers it seems that they don't really describe the abovementioned method in full. I'll try to work on it, but if you have some links or references, I'd be glad if you share :)